# Woocommerce not displaying COD payment option if user is not logged in

Tags: woocommerce

I have COD enabled as the Payment method. It displays COD option fine for a logged-in user but shows the following error message if the user is not logged in:-

> Sorry, it seems that there are no available payment methods for your
>   state. Please contact us if you require assistance or wish to make
>   alternate arrangements.

The following option is **Checked**

```
Allow customers to place orders without an account
```

I have checked by activating the Twenty Seventeen theme. I have also checked by **deactivating** --> **all** the plugins. I am not sure which, if any, setting could be triggering the conflict here.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

have you check this ?:

shipping settings (WooCommerce> Settings> General) cover the shipping location (WooCommerce> Settings> Shipping)

Check also the shipping classes. Are they the same for products as when shipping?

And if you have connected the payment methods correctly under payment (WooCommerce> Settings> Checkout> Payment method)

Comment: did you solve the problem ? you have check the log ?

Comment: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true); `

in your wp-config.php and check the log